# JS Extract one range from another

Tags: javascript, arrays, except

I need ready to use code on JS as I find it really hard to write it myself. Basically I have two arrays of with ranges (A and B) and I need to subtract ranges in array B from ranges in array A.
Example
Input:

```
    let A = [
      { start: 10, end: 30 },
      { start: 30, end: 60 }
    ];

    let B = [
      { start: 5, end: 20 },
      { start: 23, end: 27 },
      { start: 30, end: 80 },
    ];
```

Desired Output:

```
[
   { start: 20, end: 23},
   { start: 27, end: 30},
]
```

Comment: question is not descriptive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.